# How to send bearer token to views in ASP NET MVC 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2, bearer-token

I have a `.NET MVC` and `WEB API` project. I want to call the `WEB API controllers` from javascript but I didn't find a way to send the token to my views. I want to add the `bearer token` in `Viewbag` variable, using the below code:

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    //GetBearerToken doesn't exists
    ViewBag.BearerToken = Request.GetOwinContext().GetBearerToken();
}
```

In `_Layout.cshtml`, I added the folowing code to set `Authorization` header for all ajax requests:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.token = '@Viewbag.BearerToken';

    // Add Authorization header on ajax requests
    if(window.token) {
        (function setAjaxRequestsAuthorizationHeader(token) {
            $.ajaxPrefilter(function onAjaxPrefilter(options) {
                if (!options.beforeSend) {
                    options.beforeSend = function onBeforeSend(xhr) {
                        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
                    }
                }
            });
        }(window.token));
        window.token = null;
    }

</script>
```

Below is my Startup configuration method:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{

    // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
    //app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext(AppDbContext.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

    // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
    // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
    // Configure the sign in cookie
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
        Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
        {
            // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
            // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
            OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, User, int>(
                validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                regenerateIdentityCallback: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager),
                getUserIdCallback: id => id.GetUserId<int>())
        }
    });
    app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

    PublicClientId = "self";
    OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
    {
        TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
        Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
        AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
        AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
        // In production mode set AllowInsecureHttp = false
        AllowInsecureHttp = true
    };

    // Enable the application to use bearer tokens to authenticate users
    app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);

    // Enables the application to temporarily store user information when they are verifying the second factor in the two-factor authentication process.
    app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
    app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);

}
```

To get a `token` I also tried (in the MVC Controller methods):

```
var token = new ClaimsPrincipal(User.Identity).Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "access_token")?.Value;
```

But the value of variable token is always null.

I have also inspected all claims values but I didn't find any possible token.

How can I send the `token` to `controller views`?

**Solved**

I solved the problem by doing the following steps:

1. In `Startup.Auth.cs` I added the folowing static property:

   ```
    public static OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthOptions { get; private set; }
   ```
2. I have created an extension method for `ApplicationUser` class:

   ```
   public static async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(this ApplicationUser user, UserManager<ApplicationUser, int> manager, string type)
   {
       // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
       var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
       // Genereate Bearer token
       if (manager is ApplicationUserManager && type == DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie)
       {
           var accessTokenFormat = Startup.OAuthOptions.AccessTokenFormat;
           if (accessTokenFormat != null)
           {
               IDictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>
               {
                   ["userName"] = user.UserName
               };

               AuthenticationProperties properties = new AuthenticationProperties(data);
               AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(userIdentity, properties);

               var token = accessTokenFormat.Protect(ticket);
               userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("Access_Token", token));
           }
       }
       return userIdentity;
   }
   ```
3. I modified the method `OnActionExecuting` to send token to the client:

   ```
   protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
   {
       if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
       {
           var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;
           ViewBag.BearerToken = identity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "Access_Token")?.Value;
       }
   }
   ```
4. In `Startup.Auth.cs` use the extension method created at step 2 when creating `Identity`:

   ```
   OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser, int>(
       validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
       regenerateIdentityCallback: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager,
       DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie),
       getUserIdCallback: id => id.GetUserId<int>())
   ```

Comment: Can you add `console.log(window.token)` to your js-code in 2nd listing after you retrieve it and check if it arrives properly in js?

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to obtain a token from `OwinContext`. And yes, `window.token` is null.